# Difference between Google Cloud Firestore vs Google Cloud Spanner?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-spanner

There seems to be an increasing overlapping and proliferation of cloud database technologies.

In order to make sense of it a comparative approach might help.

What are the exact differences between Google Cloud Firestore vs Google Cloud Spanner ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) is:

> A flexible, NoSQL (non-relational) scalable database for mobile, web, and server development from Firebase and Google Cloud Platform.

On the other hand, [Cloud Spanner](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/):

> Horizontally scalable, strongly consistent, relational database service.

So the main difference between them is that one is a non-relational database while the other is relational. Furthermore, Cloud Firestore is also a real-time database, which means that for every change that takes place in the database you are instantly notified.

Comment: Firestore has two, native and datastore modes. Only Firestore in native mode is realtime.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Cloud Firestore is a fast, fully managed, serverless, cloud-native NoSQL document
database that simplifies storing, syncing, and querying data for your mobile, web, and
IoT apps at global scale. Its client libraries provide live synchronization and offline
support, and its security features and integrations with Firebase and GCP accelerate
building truly serverless apps.
Cloud Firestore supports ACID transactions, with automatic multi-region replication and strong consistency, your data is safe
and available, even when disasters strike. Cloud Firestore even allows you to run
sophisticated queries against your NoSQL data without any degradation in
performance.

[image]

Cloud Spanner is a service built for the cloud specifically to combine the benefits of
relational database structure with non-relational horizontal scale.
This service can provide petabytes of capacity and offers transactional consistency at
global scale, schemas, SQL, and automatic, synchronous replication for high
availability. Use cases include financial applications and inventory applications
traditionally served by relational database technology.